# How to create stock price alert with EXCEL/How to handle Auto refreshing data ,Dynamic data with macros

Tags: excel, vba

My aim with this is to create stock price alert(like Pop up message)/Because excel sheet contains more than 300 stock list
i don't want to scroll down excel sheet every time to check if refreshed price falls into any of these categories..

I have 8 columns in excel which consists of following information-
Column A-Stock Name
Column B-current stock price data which refreshes in every 5-10 seconds...
Column C-Ticker name
Next columns(D,E,F,G,H) i set them with manually entered prices for corresponding stocks for alert purpose.

If Refreshed price in column B falls in range 99% or 101% of columns values in D,E,F,G or H 
i want to display a pop up message with Stock name with that cell address of corresponding cell in column D,E,F,G,or H ...

For Ex. If D2,E2,F2,G2 or H2 contains value 104.50 which is static and if B2 cell update its price dynamically to 105 then, B2 value falls in range 99% of D2(103.95) and 101% of D2(106.05) of D2..Once this Condition satisfies i want a popup alert...Any kind of help to simplify this task is most appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check please the latest update of file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1itIZl3kMFR9f2Tf3ObB0qUprfp2rLm4r/view?usp=sharing

I added a scheduler, another sub iterates for each cell in B column every 5 seconds
I changed msgbox into debug.print to prevent crash excel.
You can find output messages in Immediate window:

Added:[image]

> Blockquote

Comment: Its not that simple....Please read it carefully. Column B values are Dynamic.Column D,E,F,G and H are static. For eg. If D2,E2,F2,G2 or H2 contains value 104.50 which is static and if B2 cell update its price dynamically to 105 then, B2 value falls in range 99% of D2(103.95) and 101% of D2(106.05) of D2..Once this Condition satisfies i want a popup alert....I hope you understand my query.Thanks for the reply

Comment: Check file which I've created already;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1itIZl3kMFR9f2Tf3ObB0qUprfp2rLm4r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello sir,,i  just went through your file...It shows alert only if i set prices manually in column B. But in my situation Column B fetches Real time/Current stock prices.And it wont trigger that macro to give alert...

Comment: If Target.Value < (1.01 * values2Compare(i)) And Target.Value > (0.99 * values2Compare(i)) Then
output = output & vbCrLf & "Value " & Target.Value & " in cell " & Target.Address & "  is found Close to " & "val" & i & " " & values2Compare(i)
        
ElseIf Target.Value < (1.01 * values2Compare(i)) And Target.Value > (0.99 * values2Compare(i)) Then
output = output & vbCrLf & "Value " & Target.Value & " in cell " & Target.Address & " is found Close to " & "val" & i & " " & values2Compare(i)
             Hello sir, please consider l'll modification in your code

Comment: I have no words for the Ultimate solution...Thanks